# "how fix laravel job has been attempted too many times or run too long'"

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, supervisord

I use the queue to send SMS. Worked well. Next, the problem that occurred to the Ubuntu server was that I had to reinstall the supervisor. This problem has arisen after resetting.

> production.ERROR: Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException: A queued job has been attempted too many times. The job may have previously time timed out. in /home/.../.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php:385

Comment: please check your code, it throws an error that's why it running multiple time.

Comment: use this commend to increase your execution time in queue php artisan queue:work --timeout=12000

Comment: php artisan queue:work --timeout=12000  I run it but do not work or do not show anything

Comment: I think your queue is empty that's why It not showing anything.

Comment: please check your jobs table.

Comment: I can see queue:failed  list

Comment: I run this :php artisan queue:listen and I do not have any problem. what s it?

Comment: it's similar to queue work, it old version queue run command.

Answer (score 4):

You need edit config/queue.php

```
'retry_after' => 1800, // This parameter is responsible for timeout
```

make sure the retry_after value is greater than the time it takes a job to run, this is mentioned in the queue documentation already.

Answer (score 1):

I have my queue run under supervisor in Fedora Linux Server

In my supervisord.conf

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/app/current/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
user=webapp
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/app/current/worker.log
stopwaitsecs=36000
```

And with this config File I have erro that you shows but when I remove sleep and tries flag like this

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/app/current/artisan queue:work 
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
user=webapp
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/app/current/worker.log
stopwaitsecs=36000
```

Error was gone

Answer (score 0):

If you use `$tries`, `$backoff` parameter, and `retryUntil()` method inside the same job, you need to follow an important rule:

`retryUntil()` method must be gretter than multification of `$tries` and `$backoff`.

```
$tries * $backoff < retryUntil
```

Example:

```
<?php

class ExampleJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, Queueable;

    public $tries = 5;

    public $backoff = 1;

    public function handle(): void
    {
        throw new Exception("Error");
    }

    public function retryUntil()
    {
        return now()->addSeconds(10);
    }
}
```

In this example, the number of tries is 5, and there is a 1-second delay between each try and retryUntil() method is set to 10 seconds,

```
    $tries * $backoff < retryUntil
    5* 1 < 10 = 5 < 10
```

Hear 5 seconds is less than 10 seconds.I think This setup will be work without throwing an error.